# Ember.js 1.0.0: Hide a "floating" menu View when user clicks off the view

Tags: ember.js

I'm very new to Ember.js and I am trying to implement what I think is a very basic behavior for "floating" menus (i.e., a menu, panel, or modal, that is absolutely positioned above the rest of the page) where the menu closes when the user clicks off the menu.

When the user clicks on a button, I open a "floating" menu (just a div with some content in it).  When the user clicks off the menu (i.e., clicks anywhere on the page that is not inside the menu) I want the menu to close.

I cannot figure out how to get this behavior to work or even what approach I should take to implement this.

I've setup a fiddle with a simple application that opens a menu when you click on the button.  The fiddle pretty much mimics the setup I currently have.  The javascript I use for the application controller, menu controller and menu view is also pasted below.  How could I modify this fiddle so that the menu will close when the user clicks off of it?

http://jsfiddle.net/LjEEP/1/

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    menuIsHidden: true,
    actions: {
        openMenu: function(){
            this.toggleProperty('menuIsHidden');
        }
    }
});

App.MenuController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['application']    
});

App.MenuView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'menu',
    classNames: ['menu'],
    classNameBindings: ['controller.menuIsHidden:hide'],
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you'd want to register a click handler for the whole document that would hide the menu, and then have another click handler on the menu div that will prevent the click from propagating up to the other handler.  Something like this:

```
   openMenu: function(){
        this.toggleProperty('menuIsHidden');        
        if( !this.get('menuIsHidden') ){
            Ember.run.next(this,function(){
                var _this = this;
                $(document).one('click',function() {            
                    _this.toggleProperty('menuIsHidden');
                });
                $(".menu").click(function(e) {
                    e.stopPropagation(); // This is the preferred method.
                    return false;        
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

Here's a modified fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ncSEG/

Comment: Fantastic!  As a new Ember user I often forget about all the jQuery functionality that is still accessible to us.  I always want to do it the "ember" way but this looks nice and clean to me.  I modified the fiddle so that when you click on the open button a second time the menu closes instead of closing and then reopening: http://jsfiddle.net/ncSEG/2/

Comment: Perfect answer!  Thanks!

Comment: Good answer and also Ember.run loop used nice and neat.